# _=> what does this underscore mean in Lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda

What does an lambda expression like `_=> expr` mean?

What is the purpose of `_` as input to lambda?

Example:

```
int count = 0;
list.ForEach(_ => count += 1);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. I took the liberty of editing your question slightly to increase your chance of getting useful answers, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Note that, assuming `list` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, they could *(and should)* have just used `sum = list.Count();`

Comment: I guess this can be used to prevent that you "pollute" the scope with a new variable name which might be used somewhere else which would cause a conflict.

Answer (score 99):

That is a convention used when you don't care about the parameter.

Comment: It's more common in Haskell and other functional languages. I think that's where it comes from.

Comment: In Haskell, ML, Scala and others, `_` is the wildcard character in pattern matching. It basically means "I don't care, I *always* want this to match". This "I don't care" then is carried over when it comes to *naming* things that you don't care about and from there, it spills over into other programming languages. It is, for example, also used in Ruby to mean the same thing as in this example, even though `_` has absolutely no special significance in Ruby.

Comment: @JörgWMittag True in May 2010, but not as of June 2010. Awesome timing! :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/6397078/38765

Answer (score 48):

It is a parameter name, albeit not a useful one, but it's the one typically used (by some conventions) when you need to specify that the expression *has* a parameter in order to get the code to compile, but you don't really care about it, so you're just going to ignore it.

It's basically exploiting the syntax for what a legal identifier in C# constitutes, and since an identifier can start with an underscore, and contain nothing else, it's just a parameter name.

You could just have easily have written:

```
var _ = 10;
```

Comment: Instead of _ , can we use () ?

Comment: Did you try using that?

Comment: Yes, I had used it when I was creating a thread using lambda expression. `Thread t= new Thread(()=>doSomething(x,y)); t.start();`

Comment: What I assume is, the use of _ is passing each variable of the collection to the lambda expression even though it's not used. But when we use () it may not happen. I mean parameter less lambda.

Comment: You need to try it using the ForEach method call. There is an overload on the Thread constructor that takes a delegate that doesn't take any parameters. Try calling a method, like that ForEach, that takes a delegate that takes a parameter instead.

Answer (score 34):

`_` is a valid variable name.  They are just using `_` as a variable.

Answer (score 11):

Because lamda expression is mostly used in a short, anonymous code so that the name of the variable sometimes is not neccessary, even they do not use the variable in the code block, so that they just give a _ for a short, convention

Answer (score 9):

I also second the use of `_ => _.method()` for one-line, method-call lambdas, since it reduces the instruction's cognitive weight. Specially when using generics, writing `x => x.method()` just adds that split-second consideration of "What's this 'x'? Is it a coordinate in space?".

Consider the following case:

`Initialize<Client> ( _=>_.Init() );`

Used with a Generics call, the underscore in this case works as a "bypass symbol". It avoids redundancy, defining that the type of the argument is obvious and can be infered from usage - just as when you use 'var' to prevent repeating a type declaration. Writing `client=>client.Init()` here would just make the instruction longer without adding any meaning to it.

Obviously, this doesn't apply to the parameters to be passed to the method, which should be named descriptively. Eg.: `Do( id=>Log(id) );`

The single-underscore-parameter usage for method calls is hardly justifiable when using a block of code instead of a one-liner, since the lambda identifier gets disconnected from its generics definition. In general when the same identifier is to be reused, give it a descriptive name.

The bottom line is that verbosity is only justifiable for disambiguation, especially for lambdas, which were created to simplify anonymous delegates creation in the first place. In any case, common sense should be used, balancing out legibility and conciseness. If the symbol is only a "hook" to the real functionality, one character identifiers are perfectly fine. That's the case with For-loops and the "i" and "j" letters as indexers.

Comment: +1 for this approach! I though I was the only one using underscores in lambdas to "reduce the cognitive weight" and not for showing that this parameter is not used. It does read easier with underscores, especially if there's lot of chaining and you can immediately infer the type, as is often the case with LINQ queries!

Comment: `Do(id => Log(id))` is better abbreviated as `Do(Log)`.

Answer (score -1):

Many C# developers use _ to indicate that the parameter isn't going to be used and a letter or other short name when the parameter is being used.

Comment: How is that *significantly* different from the other answers posted ***more than 10 (!!!) years ago***?