# When did "assigned but unused" become a warning for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, warnings

In what version or patchlevel did the following warning get added?

```
warning: assigned but unused variable - x
```

I heard about it from http://www.slideshare.net/tenderlove/nordic-ruby-2011

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick git grep showed that this was added in [this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/cf79bdc6d013687d99984dee5c79a07ea6ffca07) commit on June 16, 2010, then [reverted](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/86d72ac7cfcf5211fb6d2314df6e6d8601ff859b) on June 17, 2010 due to some problems, and was finally [added](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/47fb01e35bda888642efa577b08c3626a1eb199f) on June 20, 2010.

Note: I ran `git log --reverse -S "assigned but"` on the Ruby git repo to find these commits.

Comment: Ah, the joys of version control. Or: "Git, is there anything you *can't* do?"

Comment: Note that `_` is the special variable name to use when you won't use a variable (and thus avoid the warning). E.g.: `foo, _, bar = i_return_3_values`)

Comment: The commit suggests a ~minimal test case: ruby -we 'def m(); a=1; end'.  The warning doesn't happen at global scope.  To answer the OP's question, it also suggests that the change went in during ruby 1.9.3.  The change is fielded under that version number in eg Debian Sid's default ruby, which advertises itself as ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410).