# Ruby "don't care variable" same as Prolog's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm both new to Prolog and Ruby. Learning Prolog at university and Ruby at my own. And I was thinking if there is a "don't care" or "trow away" variable in Ruby as there is in Prolog.

I just opened irb and just did this (supposing underscore was the "don't care" sign)

```
1.9.2-p290 :003 > _, b, c = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
1.9.2-p290 :004 > b
 => 2 
1.9.2-p290 :005 > c
 => 3
```

The results are actually what I expected. But then I was curious about what where the value of underscore and what class it was

```
1.9.2-p290 :006 > _
 => 3 
1.9.2-p290 :008 > _.class
 => Fixnum
```

Well, that's odd. Shouldn't it trow the value away? Why other value being stored?

Then doing more tests with underscore I saw what actually it was happening, it has the last evaluated value.

```
1.9.2-p290 :017 > 1
 => 1 
1.9.2-p290 :018 > _
 => 1 
1.9.2-p290 :019 > "string"
 => "string" 
1.9.2-p290 :020 > _
 => "string" 
1.9.2-p290 :021 > Hash
 => Hash 
1.9.2-p290 :022 > _
 => Hash
```

So my question is: What's actually underscore for? Is it really a don't care variable or something else? What's the real name for it? (because I don't find many thing with "don't care ruby variable" with google)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559561/where-and-how-is-the-underscore-variable-specified-in-ruby

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's throwing you is that you're seeing two different uses of the underscore.

1. In argument lists, it acts like a "don't care variable," like in Prolog.
2. Outside of argument lists, it's just a normal identifier. In IRB, it's bound to the previous result. Since your last input was `c = 3`, _ is 3. This is only in IRB, though — it doesn't happen in normal Ruby programs.

Comment: so that's actually a don't care variable and it's supposed to be used to save some memory? Could you provide some link for docs?

Answer (score 9):

1. In the Ruby *community*, `_` means "don't care".
2. In the Ruby *language*, `_` doesn't mean anything, it's an identifier like any other.
3. In the YARV Ruby *interpreter*, the "unused local variable" warning is suppressed for `_`, thus encoding the convention in #1.
4. In *IRb*, `_` is bound to the value of the last expression.

Comment: Wow, didn't realize that #3 was YARV specific. Or, should I say, I [asked about it last year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397078/when-did-assigned-but-unused-become-a-warning-for-ruby) and forgot.

Comment: Actually, it might or might not be part of the Ruby Language Specification. All other implementors tend to copy YARV's error and warning messages, so, for practical purposes, it might just as well be.

Answer (score 5):

The underscore in Ruby acts like any normal variable, except it's a bit more special than that. It really does stand for "I don't care".

For, example, let's say you're looping through a array who's elements are 3-element arrays:

```
array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],...]
```

Let's say you're only interested in the middle value. With `_` you could do this:

```
array.each do |_, number, _|
  # do something
end
```

If you try to do this with another variable, you will get the (expected) error that you duplicated a variable:

```
array.each do |v, number, v|
  # do something
end

=> SyntaxError: (eval):2: duplicated argument name
```

Comment: Good one! Will accept yours. So it's not just an identifier, there is special behavior used as argument

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu: Yes, just like I said back in May…

Comment: @Chuck hmm. Now I don't know what to do. I liked this one because of the example of what you can do with the _ that you can't with normal variable. You get mad if I accept this instead of yours? Ok, I will accept yours again since you actually said this but I think this example is important

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu: Oh, I wasn't mad, I just thought it was funny. You can accept whichever you like better. No offense intended.

Comment: Yeah, I said something that Chuck didn't, and Chuck said something that I didn't. It's really your decision :). I just find this example useful for people to see.