# Why the RubyGem spreadsheet can not work in Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, excel, rubygems, warnings, spreadsheet

I have used the "sudo gem install spreadsheet" to install the spreadsheet in Mac OS X 10.7. 
But when I run an example it can not run successfully.

```
/Users/dearkx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.1/lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/workbook.rb:189: warning: assigned but unused variable - len
/Users/dearkx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.1/lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/workbook.rb:527: warning: assigned but unused variable - bef
/Users/dearkx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.1/lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/worksheet.rb:292: warning: assigned but unused variable - len
/Users/dearkx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.1/lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/worksheet.rb:599: warning: assigned but unused variable - links
/Users/dearkx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.11.3/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:232: warning: assigned but unused variable - before
/Users/dearkx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.11.3/lib/ole/types/property_set.rb:36: warning: assigned but unused variable - map
/Users/dearkx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.11.3/lib/ole/storage/meta_data.rb:79: warning: assigned but unused variable - compobj_version
⋯⋯⋯⋯
⋯⋯⋯⋯
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're just warnings, not errors. They just indicate things in the gem that the programmer shouldn't do, but Ruby will still execute the code.

These warnings were added in [2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397078/when-did-assigned-but-unused-become-a-warning-for-ruby), which might explain why it didn't appear in Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Thank you.But these warnings not exist in ruby 1.8.7 and ruby 1.9.3 for Windows Xp.Only ruby 1.9.3 for Mac OS X.

Comment: @fiigii Did you have warnings turned on for Ruby 1.9.3 for Windows XP? Also, were you using YARV, or JRuby?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to turn on the "-w" options for Winodws.