# How to merge xml streams

Tags: c#, xml

I have multiple xml streams with this format:

xml1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Node>
      <NodeA>test1</NodeA>
      <NodeB>test2</NodeB>
      <NodeC>
         <Att>test4</Att>
         <Value1>1.0</Value1>
      </NodeC>
</Node>
<Node>
      <NodeA>test1</NodeA>
      <NodeB>test7</NodeB>
      <NodeC>
         <Att>test8</Att>
         <Value1>2.0</Value1>
      </NodeC>
</Node>
...
```

xmlN:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Node>
      <NodeA>test1</NodeA>
      <NodeB>test2</NodeB>
      <NodeC>
         <Att>test4</Att>
         <ValueN>5.0</ValueN>
      </NodeC>
</Node>
<Node>
      <NodeA>test1</NodeA>
      <NodeB>test7</NodeB>
      <NodeC>
         <Att>test8</Att>
         <ValueN>6.0</ValueN>
      </NodeC>
</Node>
<Node>
      <NodeA>test9</NodeA>
      <NodeB>test8</NodeB>
      <NodeC>
         <Att>test8</Att>
         <ValueN>6.0</ValueN>
      </NodeC>
</Node>
```

I want the merged xml to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Node>
      <NodeA>test1</NodeA>
      <NodeB>test2</NodeB>
      <NodeNEW>test4</Att>
      <Value1>1.0</Value1>
      <ValueN>5.0</ValueN>
</Node>
<Node>
      <NodeA>test1</NodeA>
      <NodeB>test7</NodeB>
      <NodeNEW>test8</NodeNEW>
      <Value1>2.0</Value1>
      <ValueN>6.0</ValueN>
</Node>
<Node>
      <NodeA>test9</NodeA>
      <NodeB>test8</NodeB>
      <NodeNEW>test8</NodeNew>
      <Value1></Value1>
      <ValueN>6.0</ValueN>

</Node>
```

So I create unique keys NodeA>NodeB>NodeNEW with different Value1, ... ValueN which are assigned nothing if this unique key does not appear in its respective xml.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Deserialize, merge, serialize.

Comment: Have you tried to create corresponding models and then mark properties with xml attributes like `xmlElement` and then load your models. Than merge them programmatically into third model, after which, use xml serializer to serialize into your new xml. See code in here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Below code should give you desired results it will not show the value of previous nodes if it is not published but you can play around and get that working too. Idea here is to read items using XMLReader and update existing nodes in the same iteration.

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {

  //Ideally you should have well formed xml with root element as eg given below
  //but since it is stream it is possible but not sure how much control you have on it.
  //eg: <Nodes><Node1/><Node2/>...</Nodes> 

  //Reading your data from locally stored stream files
  var streamFiles=new[] { @"C:\temp\stack\xml1.xml", @"C:\temp\stack\xmlN.xml" };

  var dict = new Dictionary<int,XElement>();

  foreach(var streamFile in streamFiles) {
    using(var reader=XmlReader.Create(streamFile, new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel=ConformanceLevel.Fragment })) {
      var nodeNo=0;
      while(reader.MoveToContent()==XmlNodeType.Element) {
        var element=XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
        //Now merge the data. Yahoo
        XElement currentElement;
        if(!dict.TryGetValue(nodeNo, out currentElement)) {
          currentElement = new XElement("Node");
          dict.Add(nodeNo, currentElement);
        }

        foreach(var el in element.Elements().Where(e => !e.HasElements)) {
          currentElement.SetElementValue(el.Name, el.Value);
        }

        currentElement.SetElementValue("NodeNEW",
          element.Elements().Where(e => e.HasElements)
            .SelectMany(e => e.Elements()
              .Where(w => w.Name=="Att"))
            .FirstOrDefault().Value);

        currentElement.Add(element.Elements().Where(e => e.HasElements)
          .SelectMany(e => e.Elements()
            .Where(w => w.Name!="Att")));

        nodeNo++;
      }
    }
  }

  using(var writer=XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\temp\stack\xmlMerged.xml",
    new XmlWriterSettings {
      ConformanceLevel=ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
      Indent=true
    })) {
    foreach(var element in dict.Values) {
      element.WriteTo(writer);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Give your variables useful names. [Don't use underscores as variable names if you're not ignoring that variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778362/what-does-this-mean-in-lambda-expressions).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I picked up this habit of using underscore but after your comment its usage is now clear. Updated the code as well.

Comment: What do you mean by " it will not show the value of previous nodes if it is not published "? looking at your implementation how does it add ValueN as an extra entry after Value1?

Comment: and i dont get how it checks whether the existing 'NodeA>NodeB>NodeNEW' combination exists already or not. You only seem to use a number as the key in the dictionary.

Comment: 1. In your example in last merged node empty Value1 tag would not be generated. To fix this all previous sequence numbers are to be iterated.

Comment: 2. There is a loop which is loading xml files 1 by one. In each iteration nodeNo is resetting to 0 which is acting as sequence number. Now, in first iteration initial set of values would be added in dictionary with nodeNo. In subsequent iteration if node is already existing it will simply append otherwise create new as the code is same.