# C# 7.0 type pattern matching usage without variable

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

Assuming that I have `Base` and `Child1`, `Child2`, `Child3` classes, I have the following code:

```
Base b; // value is acquired
switch (b) 
{
    case Child1 child1:
        ProcessChild1(child1);
        break;

    case Child2 child2:
    case Child3 child3:
        ProcessAnyOther(b); // <--
        break;

    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(b));
}
```

Note that at the commented line I don't need these `child2`, `child3` variables since it doesn't matter what type it has, if it is not `child1`.
Resharper suggests me that unused variable can be safely removed. Here comes the interesting part.

1. I cannot do that:

   ```
   case Child2:
   case Child3:
   ```

   since it results into "class name is not valid at this point" syntax error.
   This usage seems the most appropriate for me.
2. I cannot do that:

   ```
   case Child2 nevermind:
   case Child3 nevermind:
   ```

   since it results into "conflicting variable" error. By the way, this statement would make sense if `ProcessAnyOther` method accepted more precise type (base for `Child2` and `Child3`) and I called it with `nevermind` argument instead of `b`.
3. However, I can do that:

   ```
   case Child2 _:
   case Child3 _:
   ```

   And it does not even create "_" variable. 
   That's exactly what Resharper suggests to do.

My question is: what is this? Where else can it be used? How is this "_" operator or language part called? Is it a part of C# language specification?

Comment: This is a "discard" name. It has been [used unofficially for quite a while](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2778362/335858), but C#7 makes it official in several contexts.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42920622/993547

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called a [discard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/06/27/c-7-series-part-4-discards/) and yes it is part of the C#7 specification.

From the linked article:

> Discards are local variables which you can assign but cannot read from. i.e. they are “write-only” local variables. They don’t have names, instead, they are represented as a `_` is a contextual keyword, it is very similar to var, and `_` cannot be read (i.e. cannot appear on the right side of an assignment.)

By naming the variable `_` you tell the compiler that you will never access this variable again, so it can ignore the problems you have in your first two versions.